# How to show WYSIWYG editor for product description in magento 1.7, without having it in a popup?

Tags: php, magento, wysiwyg, product, magento-1.7

I try to modify magento 1.7 product description to show WYSIWYG editor by default, without having user to click on "WYSIWYG Editor" button, but im fail to find the code where to edit, anyone can give some tips here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's an option in the Magento admin:

Admin ->System -> Configuration -> Content Management

Comment: This setting does not apply to products, only to CMS content.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer by Andrew should be correct. Magento forms should do a check to see if WYSIWYG is enabled.

```
Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()
```

This is just checking the setting you are changing with the answer previously posted:

Admin ->System -> Configuration -> Content Management

This by default will then show the nice interface and not force a pop up or action to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was originally posted here by [Nikitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091082/nikitas):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307722/3254362

I am copying the answer here for simplicity...

---

After a little research i found it.

1) Put this code in the .phtml file you want the editor to appear directly.

2) In the 6th line of the code you can see `elements: "short_description"`. You can change `"short_description"` with the element id you want. You can add more than one element id separated with comma and without spaces.

**Example:** I put this code in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml` because i want the editor to appear directly when i edit product's description, short description etc.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
   tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements: "short_description",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "inlinepopups,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,|,visualchars,nonbreaking",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
    extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
    theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
    apply_source_formatting : 'true',
    convert_urls : 'false',
    force_br_newlines : 'true',
    doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'

  });
};
</script>
```