# Magento add wysiwyg to custom frontend form

Tags: magento

I'm writing a module, and i'm searching how to add build-in wysiwyg editor to textarea in frontend. It is possible? Does anyone knows, how to implement that?

Comment: Hi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767894/magento-add-wysiwyg-editor-to-custom-widget/15953843#15953843 might help you.

Comment: No, it's not what i'm looking for. Your link describes how to use wysiwyg in widget form. I need add wysiwyg edidor to field in customer account form. Form is generateg using .phtml template.

Comment: ohh.. let me go through that.

Comment: You can try this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304960/how-to-enable-wysiwyg-by-default-on-textarea-in-admin

Comment: You are the best. It's exactly, what i need

Comment: Well Thanks in that case. My motto is to always help people around in Magento :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I am keeping this as the final solution just in case anyone need it :

1) Put this code in the .phtml file you want the editor to appear directly.

2) In the 6th line of the code you can see `elements: "short_description"`. You can change `"short_description"` with the element id you want. You can add more than one element id separated with comma and without spaces.

**Example:** I put this code in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml` because i want the editor to appear directly when i edit product's description, short description etc.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
   tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements: "short_description",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "inlinepopups,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,|,visualchars,nonbreaking",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
    extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
    theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
    apply_source_formatting : 'true',
    convert_urls : 'false',
    force_br_newlines : 'true',
    doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'

  });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciated Man.. Thankfully helping others too :)

Comment: I got Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined error in frontend

Comment: how to make this field required??

Comment: @Piyush : isn't it already a required field for you ? Can you email me your issue or explain here a bit more.

Comment: using this code i successfully added wysiwyg editor in frontend but while submitting its required field validation is not working

Comment: @Piyush : I understand your point and can definitely look into it. Have you tried anything from your side ?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is getting `ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined` error in console, here is solution for you : [Magento wysiwyg editor in phtml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896156/magento-wysiwyg-editor-in-phtml-file/34901741#34901741)

i.e. You need to include `js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_jquery.js`